# UV unwrapping and Glass texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I am currently making a syringe in Blender. One problem I have is the material. It looks very unrealistic. Yes, I know that they are normally made out of plastic, but this one has to be glass. Here is my Node Setup:

[image: Node Setup]

Also, more importantly, I have the unwrapped a texture onto the glass. If I am moving only the faces with the texture around, it only allows me to put the texture until a several point/line. A [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivywelcz53fj0qf/Blender_%20%5BC__Users_Spiele_Desktop_Grafik_Arbeiten_Aktuelle%20Arbeiten_Spritze.blend%5D%2017.09.2016%2014_41_10.mp4?dl=0) about my problem.

At the end, I want the whole texture look like this, except the main thing, where the fluid is in the glass. Currently it looks like this:

[image: result]

Here is the .blend file
[image]

Comment: Could you provide blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add it to the question?

Comment: The object you are dealing with has two qualities: Glossy and Transparent. Flat lighting is not helping you show any of them. Make the environment and the lighting more interesting, so that you can see the properties of the materials.

Comment: Looks much better now! Thanks! But it is still not perfect. If anyone still has suggestions how to improve it, I'd be happy. Additionally, the UV problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You desperately need an HDR background (in the world settings).

You can find free HDRs all over the internet but I personally prefer Greg Zaal's because he actually releases high quality, free ones:

http://adaptivesamples.com

Add an HDR with an environment node in the cycles world settings something like this:

[image]

A single ground plane will help a bit, but this is how you need to really get better looking glossy materials if you don't have an entire scene already filled in.

You can read about this technique and other material techniques here:

http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/making-better-materials/

Comment: This isn't what I was Looking for exactly, but it kinda helps. Thanks!

Comment: Since this project isn't in my interest anymore I mark your answer as accepted since it really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, making glass/glossy materials in a blank scene will make the object look dull, because the light bounces off the object and his the background, which is all the same colour. Try adding a plane for the ground and see if that makes it look better.

Comment: actually there is a plane beneath it, as you also can see in the .blend file.